# Having trouble with Puma when deploying Rails app (with Capistrano on EC2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm attempting to deploy a Rails app on EC2 for the first time and am unsuccessful in doing so. My app works locally. When I execute cap production deploy, it deploys with no errors and it seems the database is migrated and appears on my EC2 server however I'm unable to access the page and get a time out error. Also when I attempt to restart Nginx, nothing happens. I think the problem is with Puma.

When I checked the path where the puma.sock file should be located, the directory is empty. I tried to manually start Puma, to create a file with

```
bundle exec puma -e production -b unix:///home/deploy/byc/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
```

and it does not start. I get the error:

```
[28924] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[28924] * Version 3.11.3 (ruby 2.5.0-p0), codename: Love Song
[28924] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[28924] * Environment: production
[28924] * Process workers: 2
[28924] * Preloading application
[28924] * Listening on unix:///home/deploy/byc/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/Users/matt/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/puma)
```

Needless to say, it also does not work when opened by Capistrano and I'm unable to deploy the app.

This is my first time deploying anything and I've gone through dozens of questions over the past 2 days and have no idea what to do. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be forever grateful.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/default**

```
upstream app {
  # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
  server unix:/home/deploy/byc/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock         fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  root /home/deploy/byc/public;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection '';
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location ~ ^/(assets|fonts|system)/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx./conf**

```
    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

http {
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

**production.rb**

```
server 'xx.xxx.xx.xx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app db}
```

**Capfile**

```
require "capistrano/setup"
require "capistrano/deploy"
require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
require "capistrano/rvm"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock "~> 3.10.1"

set :application, 'byc'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:githubusername/byc2.git'
set :branch, :master
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/byc'
set :user, 'deploy'
set :pty, true
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system public/uploads}
set :keep_releases, 5
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.5.0' # Edit this if you are using MRI Ruby

set :puma_rackup, -> { File.join(current_path, 'config.ru') }
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_conf, "#{shared_path}/puma.rb"
set :puma_access_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_error.log"
set :puma_error_log, "#{shared_path}/log/puma_access.log"
set :puma_role, :app
set :puma_env, fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, 'production'))
set :puma_threads, [0, 8]
set :puma_workers, 0
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_preload_app, false

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
    end
  end
end
```

**database.yml**

```
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: byc-master_db
  pool: 5
  username: matt
  password:
  host: localhost
  timeout: 5432

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: byc_production
  username: byc
  password: *****
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```

Comment: Do you symlink your nginx.conf?

Comment: Yes I did. No change.